# Python Install pyPdf Error 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 64

Tags: python, pypdf

I am a beginner at PYTHON. I need to write a code to combine pdf files by using python. I use Jupiter. Before I use python to combine the pdfs. I need to install the pyPdf module.

here is my code and error message:

```
!pip install pyPdf

Collecting pyPdf
  Using cached pyPdf-1.13.tar.gz (35 kB)

Keyring is skipped due to an exception: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 64: invalid start byte
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\pip-install-4hgsun2y\\pypdf\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\pip-install-4hgsun2y\\pypdf\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-pip-egg-info-_tt28r57'
         cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-4hgsun2y\pypdf\
    Complete output (28 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2848, in get_entry_map
        ep_map = self._ep_map
      File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2810, in __getattr__
        raise AttributeError(attr)
    AttributeError: _ep_map
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-4hgsun2y\pypdf\setup.py", line 21, in <module>
        setup(
      File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 421, in __init__
        for ep in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('distutils.setup_keywords'):
      File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 640, in <genexpr>
        for entry in dist.get_entry_map(group).values()
      File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2850, in get_entry_map
        ep_map = self._ep_map = EntryPoint.parse_map(
      File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2539, in parse_map
        maps[group] = cls.parse_group(group, lines, dist)
      File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2517, in parse_group
        ep = cls.parse(line, dist)
      File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2495, in parse
        raise ValueError(msg, src)
    ValueError: ("EntryPoint must be in 'name=module:attrs [extras]' format", 'conda = conda.cli.main_pip:mai~0')
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Thank you very much.

JH

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use code

```
!pip install pyPdf
```

or

```
!pip install PyPDF2
```

none of them work.

If you have the same issue, you can try
[image]

and find the module here

https://anaconda.org

[image]

I got result:

To install this package with conda run one of the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pypdf2

conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken pypdf2

conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 pypdf2

conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 pypdf2
```

I copied the first one to the Anaconda Prompt.

It works!